# Mongoose search documents by object fields of an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document purchase having list of items. Each item has itemName and quantity.

So how do I query for all Purchase documents having quantity 10 for itemName 'keyboard'?

```
Purchase = new Schema({
  items: [{
    itemName: String,
    quantity: Number,
  }]
});
```

Comment: `Purchase.find({ "items.quantity": 10, "items.itemName": "keyboard" }).exec(callback);`

Comment: This won't work because it expects that `items` is Object which has properties `quantity` and `itemName`.

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov you can search arrays [like that](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index). However, it won't work because it will match _any_ item with a quantity of 10, not specifically _"keyboard"_ items.

Comment: @robertklep oh, thank you for explanation, in this case `$and` operator should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) operator in this case:

```
Purchase.find({
  items: {
    $elemMatch: {
      itemName: 'keyboard',
      quantity: 10
    }
  }
}).exec(function(err, items) {
  // Code goes here
});
```